# sign of odd central moments of binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, moments, binomial-distribution

I am interested in the sign of odd, central moments of a binomial distribution. From DOI. 10.1137/070700024 I have the formulae:

$ E\left[\left(X-\mu\right)^d\right]= \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\left(-p\right)^i\sum_{l=0}^{i}\left(-1\right)^l\binom{i}{l}\left(l-\mu\right)^d$

where i can see that in the odd case the sign of $\left(l-\mu\right)^n$ changes if $l > pn$. But I get no control about all the other stuff, not even the inner sum.

Another way to approach that, also from this paper mentioned above, would be to use the identity:
$E\left[\left(X-\mu\right)^d\right]= \sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\left(-\mu\right)^{d-i}E\left[X^d\right]$

and take advantage of the fact that:

$\left(np\right)^d \leq E\left[X^d\right] \leq n^d$

I would highly appreciate to derive the sign of an odd, central moment in dependence of $p$ and $n$, where $p \neq 0.5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ have the binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$. Then for any natural $d$
$$E(X-np)^d=E\Big(\sum_1^n Y_i\Big)^d,$$
where $Y,Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are iid random variables such that $P(Y=q)=p=1-P(Y=-p)$, with $q:=1-p$. Let $d$ be a natural number.

Suppose now that $p\le1/2$. Then for all natural $k$
$$m_k:=EY^k=pq(q^{k-1}-(-p)^{k-1})\ge0.$$
Also, $E\Big(\sum_1^n Y_i\Big)^d$ is a linear combination with positive coefficients of terms of the form $m_{k_1}\cdots m_{k_j}\ge0$ with natural $k_1,\dots,k_j$.

Thus, $E(X-np)^d\ge0$ if $p\le1/2$. By symmetry, $E(X-np)^d\le0$ if $p\ge1/2$ and $d$ is odd.

Working slightly harder, we can see that, if $d$ is an odd number $\ge3$, then
$$
E(X-np)^d\begin{cases}
>0&\text{ if }0<p<1/2,\\
<0&\text{ if }1/2<p<1,\\
=0&\text{ if }p=1/2.
\end{cases}
$$